# YouTube PHP API - Getting status of previously uploaded video?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Just started digging into the YouTube PHP API and got the browser-based Zend upload script working. However, I can't find any documentation on how to retrieve the status of the video after it's been uploaded. The main reason I would need this is for error handling - I need to be able to know whether the video was approved by YouTube, since someone could technically upload an image or a file too large. I need to know that the vid was approved so that I know what message to display the end user when they return to the site (ie 'Your video is live' or 'Video upload failed').

The YouTube PHP browser-based upload returns a URL parameter status of `200` even if the format or size is incorrect, which is of course not helpful. Any ideas on how else to get this info from the YT object?

All in all, when a user returns to the site, I want to be able to create a YT object based on their specific video ID, and want to be able to confirm that it was not rejected. I'm using ClientLogin to initiate the YouTube obj:

```
$authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
              $username = 'myuser@gmail.com',
              $password = 'mypassword',
              $service = 'youtube',
              $client = null,
              $source = 'MySource', // a short string identifying your application
              $loginToken = null,
              $loginCaptcha = null,
              $authenticationURL);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why you cannot check that user is not uploading too big file before sending it to YouTube?

Comment: Because that's not the question I'm asking :)

Comment: yes that is not it. But wouldn´t be easier just to check if the file is too large?

Comment: That could work in the one instance, but I'm focusing more on error handling. YouTube will upload any file and return a `200` status whether it's a movie, .jpg, word doc, etc. I would still need to be able to check a specific movie ID to see what the status is before I can display information to the user. Yes, you could check for those also, but I was hoping there was something built-in to YouTube's API.

Comment: ok, then you maybe need to wait someone to answer. I´m sorry but don´t know the answer =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whew, finally found the answer to this after searching around and piecing together code for the last few days. After you create the `$yt` object, use the following to check the status:

```
$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
$youtubeEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry('YOUR_YOUTUBE_VID_ID', null, true);

if ($youtubeEntry->getControl()){
    $control = $youtubeEntry->getControl();
    $state = $control->getState()->getName();
}
```

Echoing out `$state` displays the string `'failed'` if the video was not approved for whatever reason. Otherwise it's empty, which means it was approved and is good to go (Guessing the other state names would be: processing, rejected, failed, restricted, as Mient-jan Stelling suggested above).

Crazy how tough this answer was to put together for first-time YouTube API'ers. Solved! (Pats self on back)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a CallToken if so its pretty easy.

For this example i use Zend_Gdata_Youtube with Zend AuthSub.

WHen uploading your video you had a CallToken, With this call token you can access the status of the video.

```
$authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
          $username = 'myuser@gmail.com',
          $password = 'mypassword',
          $service = 'youtube',
          $client = null,
          $source = 'MySource', // a short string identifying your application
          $loginToken = null,
          $loginCaptcha = null,
          $authenticationURL);

$youtube = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube( $httpClient, '', NULL, YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY );
```

---

```
$youtubeEntry = $youtube->getFullVideoEntry( 'ID_OF_YOUTUBE_MOVIE' ); 
// its the 11 digit id all youtube video's have
```

---

in $youtubeEntry all your data about the video is present

```
$state = $youtubeEntry->getVideoState();
```

if state is null then your video is available else make of state a string like this.

```
(string) $state->getName();
```

There are about 4 important state names. ( processing, rejected, failed, restricted)

Comment: Not sure if I can use a calltoken here; I'm allowing users to publish via web upload to one specific YouTube channel account. There is no login or user authentication being used, just an upload to a channel. Thoughts?

Comment: If it helps, I'm using ClientLogin to initiate the object. I've added the code in the original question above.

Comment: Ok, then your almost there. You have a httpclient so getting your video state is pretty easy now. i've made a edit above so i hope that helps.

Comment: you where a bit quick a was still editing the code above. its finished now :D

Comment: Ok, you lost me. In your example, there's no place to pass in the ID of the video whose status I'd be checking. Remember, this check happens later on when a user returns to the site and the video has already been submitted to YouTube.

Comment: ok, now i'm lost. When uploading the video you use $youtube = new Zend_Gdata_Youtube(); $newEntry = $youtube->insertEntry( some data ); $youtubeVideoId = $newEntry->getVideoId();. Now you have the youtube id that id you can use to check the state of the video with $youtubeEntry = $youtube->getFullVideoEntry( 'ID_OF_YOUTUBE_MOVIE' );

Comment: Ok, I misread part of your code response revision. However, when I echo out `(string) $state->getName()` I get the following error: **Call to a member function getName() on a non-object**. Otherwise your example works to that point...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3796/discussion-between-mindsculpt-and-mient-jan-stelling)

Comment: if the state is null then the video is available. Please read my poste better. And really dont claim you found it your self even if the same awnwser is given by me.